# Does C++ provide built in multi threading support?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I want to buid a project like daily alarm. I want to do this in c++. For this I need multi threading.
Is C++ provide built in multi threading support like java Thread Class? Or is there any other reliable way to do this?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread

Comment: There are threads on c++11, other than you would need to rely on OS-specific libraries (e.g. pthreads) or other abstractions (e.g. ACE library)

Comment: What is the main difference of c++ between c++11. Is that updated version of c++? @jsantander

Comment: @user3490293: C++11 is the current version of C++.  The C++11 version of the ISO C++ Standard was approved in 2011.  Work is being done on the next version, expected to be approved this year and become C++14.  If you're familiar with Java, you'll know about the Java 1.6.x to Java 1.7.x to Java 1.8.x process.  C++ evolves similarly, except it's under the control of ISO instead of a single company, so changes are slower.

Comment: Googled this, looks relevant by the title: http://blog.smartbear.com/c-plus-plus/the-biggest-changes-in-c11-and-why-you-should-care/

Comment: A different question is whether you need threads for a daily alarm...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In c++11 using a thread is very simple, first include thread header, then pass functor you want to run into the thread constructor.

Be sure to join the thread once you're done, otherwise it's an UB.

```
#include <thread>

int main() {
  std::thread work([]() { std::cout << "Hi from a thread!" << std::endl; });
  work.join();
}
```

Threads are not copyable, but they are movable, so you can return a thread from a function call for example.

Werner's post has link to the ultimate site for all things C++ - cppreference.com, there's thread support library is described along with futures and async - two powerful concepts that might be helpful in implementing your multithreading code more naturally.

Answer (score 3):

Starting with C++11 C++ has classes for multithreading support. The class you might be interested in most is `std::thread`. There are also classes for synchronization like `std::mutex`. You can see an overview of the classes here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread.

Comment: You should add a bit more detail.  At least the names of several important classes, for the OP to continue his search.

Comment: Unsurprisingly, it's called std::thread. There are also more interesting things like std::future and async/await coming too.

Answer (score 3):

Some ideas:

- If on c++11: threads are present in the standard library: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread
- boost provides also some threads (independent of c++11): http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/thread.html
- You might want to check OS-specific libraries, e.g. unix/linux typically have available pthread (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX_Threads)
- There communication libraries that provide OS-independent abstractions, for example ACE: http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/ACE.html

Comment: I will accept your answer. One more request. Can you give me link of a small example. @jsantander

Answer (score 1):

in c++ 11, yes.
include the thread header, then start building your multi-threaded application
a book worth reading, is [c++ concurrency in action](http://www.amazon.ca/C-Concurrency-Action-Practical-Multithreading/dp/1933988770)
it will teach you how to deal with the issue of race conditions, how to make thread safe containers and very important, how to create your threadpool class